# Write image file to database as BLOB (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to enter some image file that is in ../img/test.jpg into the database

If I do $image = file_get_contents('../img/test.jpg')

And then mysql command "INSERT into table(picture) VALUES ('$image')" it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And “doesn’t work” means what? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape it properly:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (picture) VALUES ("'
    . mysql_real_escape_string($image) . '")');
```

Comment: Oops, fixed. Too used to "?" style

Answer (score -2):

Keep the image on the filesystem. You're making MySQL work too hard sending the image through a socket to your PHP script. Then you make Apache work too hard while PHP is blocking waiting for the image data from MySQL.

I don't see a valid reason why you want to save it as a mysql Blob. It gets written to the filesystem anyway by mysql.

Just save the path in MySQL.

Comment: those who down voted this answer could write a comment and explain why this answer is not good