# Saving image to mySQL db and printing it

Tags: php, mysql, image, escaping, store

To save an image I'm using:

```
$image_bin = addslashes(file_get_contents($img_url));
mysql_query('INSERT INTO images
        (image_filename, image_type, image_bin)
    VALUES
        ("file.jpg", "image/jpeg", "'.$image_bin.'")');
```

To show:

```
$qry = 'SELECT image_filename, image_type, image_bin
    FROM images
    WHERE image_id = 1';
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
header('Content-type: '.$row['image_type']);
echo stripslashes($row['image_bin']);
```

Image is saved to database, but image size gets bigger.
And image colors becomes somewhat corrupted.

For example images screenshot in Chrome with developer tool opened:
[screensho url](http://www.imagetoo.com/?v=snapshot1b.jpg)

Anyone know what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: try to use `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `addslashes`

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118156/write-image-file-to-database-as-blob-php?

Comment: @halfer Indeed, there should be some **proper** escaping in the query. But I don't think this is the cause of the problem here.

Comment: Philipp, results are same.
For me its weird that when I use same method to upload a file everything goes well :/

Comment: What is your table schema? (the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE images`)?

Comment: If there would be escaping problem, then image wouldn't be printed at all

Comment: So it was escaping problem O.o
Thanks everyone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving images in database mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753193/saving-images-in-database-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

Try...

```
//use mysql real escape
$image_bin = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($img_url));
mysql_query('INSERT INTO ' . PREFIX . 'news_images
    (image_filename, image_type, image_bin)
    VALUES
    ("file.jpg", "image/jpeg", "' . $image_bin . '")');


$qry = 'SELECT image_filename, image_type, image_bin
    FROM images
    WHERE image_id = 1';
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
header('Content-type: ' . $row['image_type']);
echo $row['image_bin']; //no stripslashes
```

Comment: Who that was spot on. Stripslashes where messing everything up.
Thank you