# How to upload a PNG, add transparent pixels to it, and write it to a database?

Tags: php, database, http, image-processing

I am looking for information on how to retrieve a PNG file sent to the server via POST. Subsequently, I want to increase the height of the image to make it equal to the width by adding equal areas of transparent pixels to the top and bottom. Finally, I want to write this PNG to my database.

Does anybody have any resources that could help?

Comment: This should ideally be split into multiple questions, but I'll touch on your last question. It's 'normally' best to store the image in a folder and then store the file name and path in a database, that way the database does not become bloated in size. Do you actually need the file stored in your database?

Comment: i  could potentially have millions of 256x256 transparent pings that will be tied to userIds and my application needs to be able to pull these bitmaps down over 3g network.. was thinking blob data would be best.. all images will be in one table with a uniqueID and a user ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will give you the way to upload the png image and check if it's a png one. Now to change the height and width of the image you should use the GD library or ImageMagick.

Check here: [PHP crop image to fix width and height without losing dimension ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255773/php-crop-image-to-fix-width-and-height-without-losing-dimension-ratio)

In order to INSERT into in the DB as a BLOB check here:

[Write image file to database as BLOB (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118156/write-image-file-to-database-as-blob-php)

```
<?php // upload.php

echo <<<_END
<html><head><title>PHP Form Upload</title></head><body>
<form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'> 
Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
</form>
_END;

if ($_FILES)
{
   $name = $_FILES['filename']['name']; 
   $type = $_FILES['filename']['type']; 
   $size = $_FILES['filename']['size']; 
   if ($type == "image/png") {
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $name); 

   /* once the image has been uploaded change the height and width using the 
   correct library and insert into the DB as a BLOB */

}else{
   die("You must upload a png file");
}
echo "</body></html>"; ?>
```

Comment: you rock.  i was going to actually post the image from an APP so it was just going to be a POST data url request. the move_upload line.. where is tmp_name being set and what is that line actually doing?

Comment: tmp_name is given directly from the $_FILES array, so you do not have to mind about it and it is what the name itself suggest, a temp name. The move_uploaded_file will then get the tmp_name and storing the image with its real name. You can also add the path just by adding the path variable before the $name variable. Like this: move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");. Do not forget to declare the $uploads_dir variable in your code.

Comment: do i have to actually write the file to the server? or is that just the example.. I was thinking i could just take the file change the canvas size to be HeightxHeight resize to 256x256, encode as png, and turninto blob data

Comment: I think that you can bypass the process of uploading the image just by working on the tmp file instead that on the moved file. But you have to give it a try with GD or ImageMagick as shown in the link I gave you

Comment: thanks again guys, and forgive me, but that link seems to be cropping the image, and i and while i can see what they are doing i am still at a lost as to do what i want.. I am going to post an image that is say 480x800 png.  I want to make it 800x800 by adding empty space to the top and bottom of the image and then resize the 800x800 to 256x256 and then save the blob

Comment: Please post another question with the code you are writing. We will try to help you out